# Perl 5: Cannot get file handle descriptor

Tags: perl, file, file-descriptor

test.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;

BEGIN {
  *CORE::GLOBAL::close = sub (;*) {
      my @Args = @_;
      my $FileNO = fileno($Args[0]);
      print $FileNO, "\n";
      CORE::close(@Args);
  };
}

use lib '.';
use Test;
```

Test.pm:

```
package Test;

open(XXX, 'test.pl');
close(XXX);

1;
```

When I run this program (`perl test.pl`), I get:

```
Use of uninitialized value $FileNO in print at test.pl line 10.

close() on unopened filehandle 1 at test.pl line 11.
```

Where is the error?

Comment: Missing `use strict` (and `use warnings` in Test.pm). Don't call your own module `Test.pm`; there's already a standard `Test` module. `close(@Args)` is wrong because `close` imposes scalar context on its arguments.

Comment: Also see [`perldoc perlsub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes) and search for `qualify_to_ref`.

Comment: @melpomene If `close(@Args)` is wrong, then what is right?

Comment: `close($Args[0])`

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the entire `@Args` array into `CORE::close`, which is not a file handle. You need to pass in the correct element of the array. Here's an example that takes a filename from the command line, and does the right thing:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

BEGIN {
  *CORE::GLOBAL::close = sub (;*) {
      my @Args = @_;
      my $FileNO = fileno($Args[0]);
      print $FileNO, "\n";

      # the next line is where the issue is

      CORE::close($Args[0]);
  };
}

die "need file param" if ! @ARGV;

my $file = $ARGV[0];

open my $fh, $file or die $!;

close $fh or die $!;
```

I'll go further with what you have. First, I'm going to rejig things so that the override of the `CORE` function is in the `.pm` file instead of the test file, then I'm going to switch to using lexical file handles, as global bareword ones just won't work here:

`Test.pm`:

```
package Test;

BEGIN {
   *CORE::GLOBAL::close = sub (;*) {
      my @Args = @_;
      my $FileNO = fileno($Args[0]);
      print $FileNO, "\n";
      CORE::close($Args[0]);
  };
}

1;
```

Script file:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use lib '.';
use Test;

open my $fh, 'test.pl' or die $!;
close $fh or die $!;
```

Between migrating code and using lexical file handles, things should work as you would expect.

Output from running the script:

```
3
```

...and to ensure everything is in order, I'll go back to your default configuration, where the override is in the test script, not the module:

`Test.pm`

```
package Test;

open my $fh, 'test.pl' or die $!;
close $fh or die $!;

1;
```

...and the script:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

BEGIN {
  *CORE::GLOBAL::close = sub (;*) {
      my @Args = @_;
      my $FileNO = fileno($Args[0]);
      print $FileNO, "\n";
      CORE::close($Args[0]);
  };
}

use lib '.';
use Test;
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comment: You didn't answer the question at all; you simply changed the test code so it doesn't happen anymore!!! Even with your change, the OP's code fails to get the fileno and fails to actually close the file handle!

Comment: @ikegami The OPs question was "where is the error". I did the best I could based on that. I fixed the most glaring error. Where was the fix supposed to be implemented?

Comment: @ikegami addendum added. Is that better?

Comment: No. Still doesn't work for the OP's code. melpomene actually answered the OP's question in a comment

Comment: @ikegami well, please post an answer or let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Re "*Let me know where I'm going wrong*", I already said: You're not using the OP's code! Specifically, you replaced `XXX` with `$fh`.

Comment: Isn't fixing code when all you have as a question is "where is the error" the appropriate thing to do? There's no clear problem description, so where does one draw the line on what to correct? Either way, I digress... I did research, learned a couple of things, so I'm happy ;)

Comment: The OP asked about a bug in `CORE::GLOBAL::close`, and you haven't fixed it yet. It still happens after your change. You just stopped testing for it.

Comment: ok @ikegami, I respect you much as you know. I'm at a loss. I am not adept with prototypes, so I'm unaware if that's where the issue lies specifically. At this point, I respectfully request the actual fix, even if in comments, just so I know what you see that I don't.

Comment: I'm on a phone. I'm not posting an answer. I can just v point out that yours is highly incompetent and that melpomene covered the rest in their comment